# Angular4: default select option value

Tags: angular, html-select

I am trying to set the first option as a default value,but it doesn't work , do you have any solution ?

```
<select   class="form-control" name="user" id="user" required [(ngModel)]="model.userSelected">
         <option selected>-- SELECT USER-- </option>
         <option *ngFor="let user of users" [ngValue]="user">{{user.name}}</option>
</select>
```

thanks in advance.
Andrea

Comment: let me know it worked for you or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this:

`<select class="form-control" name="user" id="user" required [(ngModel)]="model.userSelected">
<option value=''>-- SELECT USER-- </option>
<option *ngFor="let user of users" [ngValue]="user">{{user.name}}</option>`

And then initialize model.userSelected as an empty string:

```
model.userSelected = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

you must need to assign value to `model.userSelected` as you are binding it with the select control. you are not passing anything in current code of yours that why its not selecting any element.

try like this , create default user with id -1 and bind it.

component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
//pull add data 
model.userSelected = {name:'', id=-1} as User;
}
```

html

--do not bind full object `user` as value , bind id of object like as done below

```
<select   class="form-control" name="user" id="user" required
                           [(ngModel)]="model.userSelected.id">
         <option [ngValue]='-1'>-- SELECT USER-- </option>
         <option *ngFor="let user of users" [ngValue]="user.id">{{user.name}}</option>
</select>
```

or

just push default element at fist in array of users, after you get all users from you call to server

```
    //push default element in array of user 
    user.unshift({name:'-- SELECT USER--', id=-1} as User);

 ngOnInit() {
    //pull add data 
    model.userSelected = {name:'', id=-1} as User;
    }
```

then

```
<select   class="form-control" name="user" id="user" required
                           [(ngModel)]="model.userSelected.id">
         <option *ngFor="let user of users" [ngValue]="user.id">{{user.name}}</option>
</select>
```